# MySQL Function Oddness When Using IN Operator

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have the below query which runs ok and returns the string `2,3`. `FN_GET_PLAN_UPGRADE_OPTIONS` is returning a `VARCHAR`.

```
SELECT FN_GET_PLAN_UPGRADE_OPTIONS(1);
```

Now when I add this function call into a WHERE clause using the IN operator it only returns the result where act_id contains `2` and no results where act_id contains `3`, there is data for both so both should be returned, any suggestions or ideas, no errors are thrown!?

```
SELECT act_id
, act_name 
FROM account_types 
WHERE act_id IN (FN_GET_PLAN_UPGRADE_OPTIONS(1));
```

Comment: The argument to `IN` must be a literal list, not a string with comma-separated values. Use `FIND_IN_SET` with a string.

Comment: Fairplay, I wasn't aware of the literal list constraint on the `IN` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you want to run is this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE act_id IN (2,3)
```

but the query you are actually running is this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE act_id IN ('2,3')
```

because your function returns a STRING (not a list of values), and since you are comparing a string with a NUMBER (act_id), MySQL will automatically cast this string to a number, so you end up running this:

```
 SELECT ... WHERE act_id IN (2)
```

you can use FIND_IN_SET to solve your problem:

```
SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET(act_id, FN_GET_PLAN_UPGRADE_OPTIONS(1))>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find_in_set()`:

```
WHERE find_in_set(act_id, FN_GET_PLAN_UPGRADE_OPTIONS(1))
```

In interprets the returned value, say `'1,2'` as a single string of length three -- rather than two different values.

Answer (score 0):

The result is desired, in fact you are saying

```
SELECT act_id
, act_name 
FROM account_types 
WHERE act_id IN ('2,3');
```

Notice, the `WHERE act_id IN ('2,3')` is completely different than `WHERE act_id IN (2,3)`.

You can also use `REGEXP` function:

```
SELECT act_id
, act_name 
FROM account_types 
WHERE FN_GET_PLAN_UPGRADE_OPTIONS(1) REGEXP act_id;
```